# Restrictions of null/meager ideal

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let I denote the null/meager ideal on reals. Is it consistent that for any pair of non null/meager sets A and B, there is a null/meager preserving bijection between A and B? In particular, is this true in the model obtained by adding $\omega_2$ Cohen/random reals over a model of CH?

Comment: You should post this on MO, if you haven't already.

Comment: If it gets asked on MO, please provide a link here.

Comment: Mathoverflow link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130222/restrictions-of-null-meager-ideal